# angular ui router, back button does cause state change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular in a rails app and have ui-router set up with several states.

```
name: 'item'
url: '/items'
```

child states

```
name: detail
url: "/{item_id:[0-9]{1,4}}/detail"
parent: item
```

I'm transition between states using

```
$state.go('detail', item_id: id)
```

All appears to be working fine except when I click the back button on the browser.

When the back button is clicked the location in the browsers address bar correctly changes to show the unique url of the previous state however the ui-router doesn't seem to change state and I get no $stateChangeStart event.

Is this the normal behaviour of ui-router or have I got something set up incorrectly?

If it is the normal behaviour is there any way I can force a state change when the back button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *normal behaviour* of `ui-router` is, that the browser *back button* is working out of the box *(exactly as we would expect)*.

Try to play with this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qlaEvdmt6MNPyPAap8nN?p=preview), there is also the listener `'$stateChangeStart'` writing into console

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location){

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
      function (event, toState, toParams){
        console.log(toParams)
      });
})
```

*(click the blue icon in the right top corner, to open the preview in separated window)* ... you can navigate among few details and then use backspace keyobard to mimic the back button... all is correctly re-trigerred... check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qlaEvdmt6MNPyPAap8nN?p=preview)